# match a pattern and assign a new value by replacing the old one's

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
name                 : Annie
CUSTOMER_ID          : 1111111

name                 : Marlon
CUSTOMER_ID          : 2222222
```

This is a text file called Sample.txt . Here i want to search for customer_id and replace the contents 1111111 and 2222222 to 123456 . So the expected output should be in Sample.txt should be of the form.

```
name                 : Annie
CUSTOMER_ID          : 123456

name                 : Marlon
CUSTOMER_ID          : 123456
```

Comment: Kindly wrap up your samples in CODE TAGS by using `{}` button in your post.

Comment: Please specify whether *all* `CUSTOMER_ID`s should be replaced with `123456` or just some of them.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50341837/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/CUSTOMER_ID/{$NF="123456"} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***
`/CUSTOMER_ID/`: Searching string `CUSTOMER_ID` in current line of Input_file and if that is found then do the action mention in `{}` braces.
`$NF="123456"`: Assigning `$NF` last field of current line value to `123456` as per OP's requirement.
`1`: `awk` works on method of condition then action so by mentioning `1` here I am making the condition TRUE and not mentioning any action so by default print of current line will happen.

In case you want to save the output into Input_file itself then use:

```
awk '/CUSTOMER_ID/{$NF="123456"} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```